# What happens to local files on iOS when the app is updated?

Tags: ios

My iOS app is writing to local files to:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A.../Library/a.txt
```

When my app updates, it gets a new application container ID and folder:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B...
```

What happens to all the files I wrote to container ID A?

Is there an "update hook" that will allow me to copy all the "A" container files to path "B"?

Can the new version of the app (B) read the old versions files (A)?

Is there any documentation around what happens to the filesystem during updates?

Is it possible to recover files from container A after B has been installed?

Comment: i don't think updating the app removes current files in Documents dir.

Comment: Think about it. What would the reaction of users be if every app update caused their data to be lost? And what has your experience been while developing your app? Every time you do another build in Xcode, it's basically the same as doing an app update. Is your data being lost between builds?

Comment: When I install different versions from the App Store and then Test Flight (and vice versa) a new container ID is generated, which means a new file path. I assumed this was the case for App Store updates too?

Comment: Yes, you get a new path during builds and app updates. But is your data disappearing? Have you ever lost app data updating any app you have on your iOS devices? As long as your app isn't storing absolute paths to files in a database or something similar, have you had a problem?

Comment: The data is not "disappearing" or being deleted. But: 1) iOS is locked down so an owner cannot just browse the filesystem with a USB cable. If the files are not in the Documents iOS dir, they are essentially inaccessible from outside the app process. 2) Each container process can only read its own files. Given 1 and 2, if your new app update is given a new container ID, it will not be able to read and write files from the previous version (point 2). And the user will not be able to read or write them either (point 1). So the files would "disappear".

Comment: @zino Again, when you do a new build, are your files disappearing? No, they are not. Things are fine. iOS copies the sandbox to the new location.

Comment: ok thanks. So the files are copied by iOS, and the container ID always changes? Or do updates from the App Store always maintain the same container ID?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the container id changes or not though you should assume it does. But if your app cares whether the container id changes or not then you have written your code incorrectly.

Answer (score 12):

When you update an app, by changing its version number in the .plist file, iOS creates a new directory for that app with a different hexadecimal name and it copies all the files to the new directories. Now if you are using the absolute paths to get the details of files from the directories then those paths would be incorrect and you won't get the file details.

I just tried this in simulator. I created a function as below which will return the document directory path url

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {

    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

I called this function from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in app delegate when version number was 1.0 and it returned the below path :

```
file:///Users/BhargavRathod/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3082611F-BCCA-4D17-B390-E0EF4CA454DA/data/Containers/Data/Application/72759097-38F3-4292-825E-1D2343219973/Documents/
```

When I updated the version number to 1.1 it returned me the new path as :

```
file:///Users/BhargavRathod/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3082611F-BCCA-4D17-B390-E0EF4CA454DA/data/Containers/Data/Application/72DC31E9-C32F-42CC-8449-F1946ADB1018/Documents/
```

So if you are using a absolute path to access any file from document directory then it is not good practice. You can just save the file name(or relative path after the document directory) and whenever the access to that file name is required then get the file name and append it after the document directory path and access the file.

I hope this will be of some help to you.

Answer (score 5):

> My iOS app is writing to local files to: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A.../Library/a.txt

Okay, stop right there. This is wrong.

*Your app has its own sandbox.* This sandbox persists forever, thru updates, as long as your app keeps its Bundle ID, and as long as the user does not delete the app.

You thus have no business knowing or thinking about the full absolute path to where your file is. All you know, and all you need to know, is that it is in your app’s sandbox in the Library directory. You can, at any time, obtain the URL of the Library directory by means of its search path:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/searchpathdirectory/librarydirectory

And that is where the file will always be. As long as you ask the FileManager for your Library directory and for the *a.txt* file within it, you will find the same file, regardless of any updates, as long as the user doesn’t actually delete your app (because that deletes the sandbox).

> Can explain what happens to the files

Nothing. They stay where they are within the sandbox. The absolute URL of the sandbox may change, but your files are unaffected.

> how to keep the files written by the previous version of the app

They are kept automatically. You don’t have to do anything.

---

(Having said all that, keep in mind that if you submit an app with a *different bundle id*, that is not a new version of your app. It is a totally different app. In that case you would have a very different problem to solve. This would be no different from any other problem of communicating files from one app to another. You’d need to put the files in a common location, make them available thru the Document Browser, make them exportable by the user, or whatever.)

Comment: Hi @matt, I follow your comment, but still I am getting new path at every launch also, the already saved file is also not there, so every time its creating as new. I asked question in this link, could you please review once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423828/ios-file-path-is-changing-at-every-launch-rerun-the-application?noredirect=1#comment112153139_63423828

Comment: @Prasanth In my view, the answers here answer the other question as well.