# File Directory Changing Every Reboot Swift iOS

Tags: swift, storage, uiimagepickercontroller, nsuserdefaults, swift5

I am currently saving images a user selects from their photo library & saving the url to User Defaults.

The issue I am currently facing is whenever my app reboots, such as an Xcode re-launch the URL I am saving to User Defaults is no longer valid. From my understanding/researching I need to save a relative URL for the image; however I am not having any luck doing this correctly. This occurs with both simulator & actual device.

From my `UIImagePicker` here are my steps:

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }

        let savingImage : SavingImage = SavingImage()

        let ourStringedUrl : String = savingImage.saveImageDocumentDirectory(image: image, imageName: image.description)

    }
```

From `SavingImage`, here is the saving of the photo itself

```
func getDirectoryPath() -> NSURL {
        let path = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("AllImages")
        let url = NSURL(string: path)
        return url!
    }


func saveImageDocumentDirectory(image: UIImage, imageName: String) -> String {
               let fileManager = FileManager.default
               let path = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("AllImages")

               if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path) {
                   try! fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
               }

           let url = NSURL(string: path)
           let imagePath = url!.appendingPathComponent(imageName)
           let urlString: String = imagePath!.absoluteString
           let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
           fileManager.createFile(atPath: urlString as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)

           return urlString as String

       }
```

& Finally here is how I am loading the image itself:

```
 func getImageFromDocumentDirectory(imageName : String) -> UIImage {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        var ourImage : UIImage!
        let imagePath = "\(imageName)"
        let urlString: String = imagePath



        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: urlString) {
            ourImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: urlString)

        } else {

            if ourImage == nil {
                ourImage = UIImage(named: "defaultImage.png")
            }

        }

        return ourImage

    }
```

Where am I going wrong with the loading aspect? How exactly should I be saving the URL?

The URL that is being saved looks something similar to the following:

```
//var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/17C16D0D-1BFA-44F5-A6BD-18DFAEA051E0/Documents/AllImages/%3CUIImage:0x280a393b0%20anonymous%20%7B3024,%204032%7D%3E
```

But will come up as nil upon loading the image on reboot.

Comment: Is it on simulator or on actul  device ?

Comment: it occurs on both simulator and real device

Answer (score 0):

The new directory will be created every time you reboot your simulator or every time you install new build to device. (Uninstall previous and install new). iOS does not give us permission to select the directory. As you install new application it will create its sandbox. Please make sure you check your directory on the same build.

Comment: So how would I go about saving the images locally without them disappearing every time there is an app update?

Comment: It is dependent on your bundle id. after production whenever there is an update for the app it will be pointing to same bundle. Therefore it will not disappear.In device where as in simulator it varies.

Comment: I see, so I won't need to worry if a User updates their app? The photo will remain there if a user updates their app?

Comment: Please see below reference link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56311164/9673374

Answer (score 0):

An alternative might be to use iCloud Drive and upload your image there. The iCloud drive is linked to an user's iCloud account, and therefore should persist in case of an app update.

Here's a great tutorial to get started: https://theswiftdev.com/2018/05/17/how-to-use-icloud-drive-documents/

Here's a link to the docs: https://developer.apple.com/icloud/icloud-drive/

Comment: The issue is I want to be able to have Users not need internet access in-order to access images they have selected from the photo library